# AppDomainUnloadedException in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have intranet asp.net application with windows authentication. Everytime after deploying new version (copying files to folder on server) I get [AppDomainUnloadedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainunloadedexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and only pool restarting can fix this problem.

Comment: Do you interop into unmanaged code or use a special library that does that like accessing Active Directory or using COM objects? Perhaps [BUG: AppDomainUnloadedException is thrown when you call a virtual destructor on a __nogc class during an AppDomain unload](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/837317) is relevant?

Comment: @Martin Liversage, no unmanaged code, for access to Active Directory I use System.DirectoryServices only, for export to excel I use OpenXmlSdk.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attempted to access an unloaded appdomain when using System.DirectoryServices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895128/attempted-to-access-an-unloaded-appdomain-when-using-system-directoryservices)